# preloading video within a queue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I using a few little video clips as well as a lot of images as part of quite a creative/visual project. Ive made a queued preloader as part of the initialization sequence of the site. The site uses javascript/jquery and basically takes an array of images and uses basically:

```
$('<img/>').load(function(){
    $.preloadQueue.loadNext();
}).attr("src",whateversrc);
```

nice an easy and it works great for images...

However, (of course) doing `$('<video/>').load(...blah` doesn't really have such consistent results.

Has anyone come across a stable cross-browser way of preloading a video (mp4/ogv etc) through javascript?